# Trying to secure multimedia files

Tags: php, security

I made a database system with PHP and MYSQL. It has a lot of sensitive information so I'm trying to put the best security.

I have a question about video and audio files. I want only people that are logged in and that actually have permission to download the files to be able to download them, not anybody that just points to the folder where the media files are. How can I do that?! Thanks!

Comment: Are you storing files in database or on file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your files via a php wrapper, i.e. `<img src="files/file.php?id=oj348jfoj" />` and in your file.php you output the file with image headers if the user has the rights to view the file. In you table, you have the real image URI that corresponds to your `oj348jfoj` token, and this is what you file.php loads and outputs as image to the requester. This way the real URI of your server files stays hidden and you get to check access rights for every image load.

Comment: Where would I put the files though? They would still be accessible through a url if they know which folder they are in?

Comment: in a folder to which you restrict outside access to via htaccess - besides, that already would require for someone to guess the right folder and filename, as you don't have it public anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to stream the file using PHP. Pass the name of the file using the query string and then write it to the page. You can check the permissions before you stream the file over.

Pseudo-code:

```
header("Content-Disposition: atachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("$path/$filename"));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$fp=fopen("$path/$filename","r");
print fread($fp,filesize("$path/$filename"));
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Comment: Where would I put the files though? They would still be accessible through a url if they know which folder they are in?

Comment: Use a .htaccess file containing `deny from all` to deny access to them.  This prevents direct request through Apache, but still allows PHP to read (and output) them.  Or a better solution is to put them above your apache document root so it's clear they aren't accessible from Apache.

Comment: I suggest you put them above your document root, that way they are not accessible using any url.

Answer (score -2):

So. The files have to be on the server, that's clear. Here's a suggestion: hide them somewhere. Then, when a user hits download, **copy** its contents to a temporary location and save into a MySQL table with expiring 10-30 minutes (could be more if HUGE files). Then the user could download from that link. Finally, run a cronjob every 10-30 minutes (the same amount) that deletes expired files.

This isn't 100% security as a non-logged in can download too, but only if a logged-in shares the URL, so then they could simply send that to them.

Comment: This is not safe and it is overly complex. You can have files that are not accessible directly instead of creating a temporary public location.

Comment: Could be complex, but this is safe as the filename could be random and as such, a non-logged in will either have to try (which is impossible) or a logged-in must share the URL but then it is just the same if they shared the file. Your point is invalid about security.

Comment: This is security through obscurity. Like you said it yourself, it is not 100% secure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: It isn't, but considering that random guessing won't work and users could share the file as well, the only problem is if that they find the actual file, which can be prevented from htaccess.

Comment: You could do it that way, but, as Bruno says, it is overly complex. Using the method Bruno shared allows additional safeguards like authenticating against a user session, without the additional costs of storing temporary files, another DB table, a cron job, etc. It's not that this is not a solution, it's just not the best solution - hence the downvotes.